# how to dynamically change whole object (inc. array) in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I use following code to dynamically update whole object in mongoDB:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){

    const Model = require('../models/' + req.body.where)
    for(let i=0; i<req.body.array.length; i++){
        Model.updateOne({
            "_id": req.body.array[i]._id,
            "user_ID": req.body.user_ID
        },{
            $set: req.body.array[i]
        }).catch(next)
        if(i+1 == req.body.array.length) res.send({})
    }

}
```

but the code is not working, when model own array:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const exerciseSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'required!']
    }
}, { _id : false })

const workout_planSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'required!']
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    user_ID: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'required!']
    },
    exercises: [exerciseSchema]
})

const workout_plan = mongoose.model('workout_plan', workout_planSchema)

module.exports = workout_plan
```

I would like to update whole object with totally new values, staying only with the same _id.

For example , I have following value in DB:

```
"_id": "604a16f6cf847c1810c8fd08",
"title": "1",
"user_ID": "Test",
"exercises": [{
"title": "123"
}],
```

and I am sending array which looks like this:

```
"_id": "604a16f6cf847c1810c8fd08",
"title": "2",
"user_ID": "Test",
"exercises": [{
"title": "234"
},{
"title": "235"
}],
```

and the result should be same as the array I am sending. How can I change my code to reach this?

PS: Basiclly I want to make object in DB = sent object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the answer is to change the main function like this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){

    const Model = require('../models/' + req.body.where)
    for(let i=0; i<req.body.array.length; i++){
        Model.replaceOne({
            "_id": req.body.array[i]._id,
            "user_ID": req.body.user_ID
        },
        req.body.array[i]
        ).catch(next)
        if(i+1 == req.body.array.length) res.send({})
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
for( let elem of req.body.array ) {
let workout_plan = await Model.findById(elem._id);

workout_plan.title = elem.title;
workout_plan.user_ID = elem.user_ID;
workout_plan.exercises = elem.exercises;

await workout_plan.save();

}
```